# SQL - Match email address text before @ symbol from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

I'm trying to match similar email addresses from two tables.  What I would like to do is find records where the email address from table 1 is similar to the email address in table 2 (where the text is the same before the @ symbol).  For example JohnSmith@gmail.com would match JohnSmith@yahoo.com.

Comment: Substring Syntax will vary across database types...what database are you in?

Comment: The data I want to match is in MS Access tables..  Our full database is MYSQL but I have read only permission so I exported my lists of email addresses to Access.

Comment: Access is very painful to work in and not sure if it'll be able to handle this.  Read permission is all you need here...Take the advice of the answers below, do it in MySQL.  Editted your question to add tags

Comment: @Twelfth re: *"Access is very painful to work in"* - No disrespect intended (well, not much, anyway) but in your case I suspect that working with Access is like sex: If it is **really** that painful then you're probably just not doing it right.

Comment: @GordThompson lets just say it's easier to dig a hole with a SQL back hoe than it is to dig with one with the tiny deformed spoon that is access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Access you can use a query like this:

```sql
SELECT
    t1.ID AS ID1,
    t1.Email AS Email1,
    t2.ID AS ID2,
    t2.Email AS Email2
FROM
    Table1 AS t1
    INNER JOIN
    Table2 as t2
        ON Left(t1.Email,InStr(t1.Email,'@')-1) = Left(t2.Email,InStr(t2.Email,'@')-1)
```

**Edit re: comment**

If you receive a "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" error due to Null values in the fields that you are attempting to join then try this

```sql
SELECT 
    t1.ID AS ID1, 
    t1.Username AS Email1, 
    t2.ID AS ID2, 
    t2.email AS Email2
FROM 
    USERS AS t1 
    INNER JOIN 
    LICENSE AS t2 
        ON Left(Nz(t1.Username,''),InStr(Nz(t1.Username,''),'@')-1) = Left(Nz(t2.email,''),InStr(Nz(t2.email,''),'@')-1);
```

**Edit 2**

...or perhaps you'd prefer something like this:

```sql
SELECT 
    t1.ID,
    t1.Username AS Email
FROM 
    USERS AS t1 
WHERE
    EXISTS
        (
            SELECT * 
            FROM LICENSE AS t2 
                WHERE Left(Nz(t1.Username,''),InStr(Nz(t1.Username,''),'@')-1) = Left(Nz(t2.email,''),InStr(Nz(t2.email,''),'@')-1)
        )
```

Comment: This appears to be working but then I get a "data type mismatch in criteria expression" error message.  Both of the IDs are Autonumber and t1.Username and t2.email are both text so I'm not sure what is causing the issue.  Could it be a problem with some of the data in the tables?

Comment: SELECT
    t1.ID AS ID1,
    t1.Username AS Email1,
    t2.ID AS ID2,
    t2.email AS Email2
FROM
    USERS AS t1
    INNER JOIN
    LICENSE as t2
        ON Left(t1.Username,InStr(t1.Username,'@')-1) = Left(t2.email,InStr(t2.email,'@')-1)

Comment: @MattJanachek Does the query in the above comment work okay for you? (It looks fine to me.)

Comment: It starts displaying results but then I get the "data type mismatch in criteria expression" error after about 20 seconds.

I made sure that all of the data has a '@' in it.  I wonder if a record with a weird email address like '@gmail.com' could be causing an issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question quickly and accurately!  With too many email addresses from both tables starting with identical first names or words like 'info' the result is turning into a Cartesian mess.  I want to match emails from t1 with t2 but don't care if t2 matches t1 so I think changing the query to a left join would do this.

Comment: @Gordon Thompson Do I need to add the USERS table to the FROM clause of the EXISTS section?  I'm getting an "Invalid procedure call" when I try to run this.

Comment: @MattJanachek No, that is not necessary. You can download a working example [here](http://wikisend.com/download/456564/email.zip).

Comment: It is definitely working when I open your db!  If I copy the query to my db I still get the "Invalid procedure call" error.  Could it be a difference in syntax between ms access 2000 and 2010?

Comment: @MattJanachek No, I actually tested that in Access 2010. I just saved it in Access 2000 .mdb format because I didn't know what version you had. I suspect that it is a data-related issue.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I found null and records without '@' symbols now the query is running.  I think its going to be a while (comparing 145k email addresses against 1k email addresses).

Answer (score 0):

Inner join tables `A` and `B` with a *theta* like this (in T-SQL syntax):

```
ON SUBSTRING(A.Email, 1, CHARINDEX('@', A.Email)) = SUBSTRING(B.Email, 1, CHARINDEX('@', B.Email))
```

When switching from MS Access to MySQL your syntax will completely change, so just go for the MySQL syntax. The above is *not* a working solution of you problem but it will guide you towards it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is MySQL syntax for doing this:

```
on substring_index(a.Email, '@', 1) = substring_index(b.Email, '@', 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQl you could do something like this just an in and selecting everying before the @, the column name is 'email' in both tables:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Email,0, CHARINDEX('@',Email)) 
from [TABLE1] 
where SUBSTRING(email,0, CHARINDEX('@',email))
in (SELECT SUBSTRING(email,0, CHARINDEX('@',email)) from [TABLE2])
```

Comment: Just saw the mySQL tag being added so guess my answer isn't relevant. Something similar might work in access though as its Microsoft and you can query two tables in access